# How apply summarise but keep other columns?

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I want group by `NAME` and sum `MONEY`, but I want to keep the other cols of `MONEY`. When I did it, my result is a `DF` with just `NAME` and `MONEY`

```
  money = money %>%
  group_by(NAME) %>%
  summarise(SUM_MONEY = sum(MONEY))
```

Comment: In case of `sum` a grouped `summarise` will create one row with the sum of `MONEY` for each `NAME`. How would you like the other columns to be summarized?  Do you also want to take the `sum` of those values? Then there is `across(your_column_selection_goes_here, sum)`. In any case it would be great to have a small example with your data and expected output.

Comment: Or if you don't want to collapse your data to one row per group, use `mutate()` instead of `summarise()`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I want keep the value of the other columns to each name. So I don't want to do nothing with them.

Comment: seems like you want `mutate` and not `summarize`. Unless you can group by them, you caanot keep whole columns with aggregated/summarized values. The two will have different number of observations/rows

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.